# Альтернативный способ проверки IP адреса при изменение его в hosts?

Tags: windows, сеть

В приложение забит IP адрес сервера, а клиент его подменяет в hosts и запросы идут уже к фейковому серверу.

Существует ли альтернативный способ проверки IP адреса сервера при изменение его в hosts?

Comment: Вам нужно проверить, дошли ли запросы приложения именно до вашего сервера? Тогда например можно вместе с запросом посылайте какой-нить уникальный идентификатор, который будет хешироваться на сервере и приложением по одинаковому алгоритму. Если хеш ответа сервера совпадает с хешем приложения, то проверка пройдена.

Comment: @mirypoko, это уже сделано. Там и TLS, и несколько видов хешей и проверок. Хотелось бы добавить еще один уровень защиты.

Comment: Т.е. нужен способ проверки на клиенте, что пакеты идут именно к моему серверу (а не подмененному через hosts).

Comment: О каком `hosts` идет речь, о том который расположен в папке Windows?

Comment: @sp7, да, как самый простой способ, доступный почти каждому.

Comment: Если пользователь укажет фейковый IP сервера, как я понимаю работать клиентская часть не будет и все. Проблема то в чем?

Comment: @sp7, просьба не спрашивать зачем и почему, причин может быть масса: (слили сервер, эмулировали сервер), а помочь делом или советом, как корректно зафиксировать подмену IP на клиенте.

Comment: Что бы помочь, нужно понимать контекст, что бы понимать контекст нужна информация, а не игра в угадайку и попытки предположить, что у вас и как.

Comment: @sp7, что непонятного? Вопрос сформулирован четко.

Comment: Если кому-то так сильно захочется использовать с вашей программой свой сервер, что дело дойдет до создания своего эмулятора, скорее всего ваша программа к тому моменту уже будет дизассемблирована и избавлена от всех механизмов защиты.

Comment: @mirypoko, верно говорите, но не учитываете один фактор. Чем больше проверок навешено, чем лучше защищен код протекторами и обфуксаторами - тем меньше желание у реверсера с ним копаться.

Comment: Как ваш вопрос коррелирует с использованными метками языков?

Comment: @alexolut, с метками все просто. Если кто-то покажет пример кода, то эти языки будут мне понятны, в отличии от VB, питона и прочих ЯП. Вопрос не только теоретический, но и практический, где в ответе для наглядности можно привести пример кода.

Comment: Для вашей задачи, имхо, не пример кода нужен, а алгоритм действий для вполне конкретной ОС. Так что тут были бы уместнее метки типа [tag:windows] и [tag:сеть], например.

Comment: @alexolut, добавил эти две метки. Предыдущие метки оставил, возможно кто-то приведет пример кода. Некоторым проще привести пример кода, чем все это подробно расписать. По коду читать проще.

Comment: Стоп, что то не понятно. Вы говорите, что в приложение забит "IP-адрес", а не имя сервера. Тогда каким образом вы предполагаете воздействие файла hosts на ip-адрес ? По файлу hosts происходит преобразование _имен_ в ip, а не ip в ip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете прописать в приложении IP-адрес напрямую или реализовать клиент протокола DNS и запрашивать адрес вашего сервера самостоятельно, не доверяя системным настройкам.

Но все это не имеет смысла, потому что при желании трафик на любой адрес можно завернуть и перехватить, это делается очень просто. Например, адрес назначается как дополнительный любому из сетевых интерфесов. Или для адреса прописывается дополнительный маршрут в таблице маршрутизации, это можно сделать как на компьютере, так и на роутере. Или же можно настроить пересылку пакетов средствами файервола, опять-таки это работает как на клиентском компьютере так и на роутере (да-да, даже самые дешевые роутеры от ноунейм-производителей имеют настройки пересылки пакетов!).

Файл `hosts` - это всего лишь самый простой способ перенаправления трафика, но если он не будет работать - хакеры быстро найдут более аккуратный способ. Поэтому нет никакого смысла в том, что вы пытаетесь сделать.

От перехвата защищает только шифрование трафика, и ничего более.

Comment: Следующие замечательные вопросы: клиент эмулирует DNS - что делать? Как изменить системный DNS на свой собственный? Как вклиниться в стек TCP/IP и анализировать роутинг пакетов?

Comment: @bukkojot никак

Comment: @bukkojot Тогда нужно свою операционку писать и кастомный системник делать -- и то не панацея...